# Automatic password confirmation in alias

Tags: unix, terminal, alias, sudo

I've got this piece of code as alias:

```
alias x='sudo ifconfig en0 ether xx-xx-xxx-xxx-x; ifconfig en0 |grep ether'
```

it asks me for password everytime. How to bind inside this alias password for sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-S` option to cause `sudo` to read the password from standard input.

Try this:

```
alias x='sudo -S ifconfig en0 ether xx-xx-xxx-xxx-x <<< mypassword; ifconfig en0 |grep ether'
```

Obviously, storing your sudo password in an alias is not secure so I would strongly advise against this.